# convert a list of data structure in string, scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

for example I have this structure:

```
(define-struct example (n1 n2))
```

and I have this list:

```
(list (make-example 1 3) (make-example 7 9) empty)
```

As I can convert it into string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have tagged both racket and scheme (two incompatible languages) I've ignored Scheme completely in my answer. I assume you would not tag [racket](/questions/tagged/racket) if you were programming in #!r5rs or #!r6rs.

```scm
#!racket

(define (any->string any) 
  (with-output-to-string (lambda () (write any))))

(any->string '(Hello world)) ; ==> "(Hello world)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Racket already has the [~ a](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html?q=%7E%A0a#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fformat..rkt%29._~7ea%29%29) procedure to do exactly that:

```
> (~a '(Hello world))
"(Hello world)"

> (define-struct example (n1 n2) #:transparent) 
> (define l (list (make-example 1 3) (make-example 7 9) empty))
> (~a l)
"(#(struct:example 1 3) #(struct:example 7 9) ())"
```

Also, note that `~a` has tons of options for formatting which may come in handy.