# convert string to list of structures scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

for example I have this structure:

```
(define-struct example (n1 n2))
```

and I have this list:

```
(list (make-example 1 3) (make-example 7 9) empty)
```

and converted to string gives me this:

```
"(#(struct:example 1 3) #(struct:example 7 9) ())"
```

as it can be converted back to a list of structures
like this:

```
(list (make-example 1 3) (make-example 7 9) empty)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want ["prefab" structures](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/structures.html?#%28tech._prefab%29).

Here's an example:

```lisp
#lang racket

(define-struct abc (a b c)
  #:prefab)

(define struct-list (list (abc 1 2 3)
                          (abc 4 5 6)))
;; => '(#s(abc 1 2 3) #s(abc 4 5 6))

(define output-port (open-output-string))
(write struct-list output-port)
(define struct-list-string (get-output-string output-port))
;; => "'(#s(abc 1 2 3) #s(abc 4 5 6))"

(define input-port (open-input-string struct-list-string))
(define struct-list-again (read input-port))
;; => '(#s(abc 1 2 3) #s(abc 4 5 6))

(equal? struct-list struct-list-again)
;; => #t
```

Comment: +1 for `#:prefab`. It makes it much more usable than without.

Answer (score 0):

Reading data in as astructure can be done this way:

```scm
(define (string->structure str)
  (with-input-from-string str (lambda () (read))))
```

Using [kayleefrye's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24167264/1565698) seems to make this struct compatible as well:

```scm
(define-struct example (n1 n2) #:prefab)  
(define in (string->structure 
            (any->string (list (example 1 3)
                               (example 7 9) 
                               empty))))
(example-n2 (car in)) ; ==> 3
```

`any->string` is from [my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24081165/1565698) about how to do the reverse. 
Basically this answer has become pretty much similar to  kayleefrye's, but I leave it here since I prefer `with-input-from-string`, but you should accept the other answer since he came up with the `#:prefab` flag.

Comment: thanks and how I can do if a list of lists, for example: `(list ((list make-example 1 3)) ((list make-example 7 9) empty))`

Comment: @user3714827 I've updated my answer with elements "stolen" from kayleefrye.